# Communication between IC and microcontroller (Teensy 3.2)

Tags: pwm, communication, rotary-encoder

I am trying to use a rotary encoder with an integrated circuit to measure the position of a rotating shaft. I am then taking this data and writing to an SD card. The IC seems to be working correctly and outputting binary data to the specified pins,  but the data does not seem to be reaching the micro-controller. My output data is fragmented, and seems to only be receiving binary data from some of the IC pins. The IC I am using is HCTL-2021-A00 (http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Avago-Technologies/HCTL-2021-A00/?qs=RuhU64sK2%252bsgeK17XZB%2fNA%3d%3d). I tried using a larger gauge wire to connect the two, but then the micro-controller didn't seem to pick up any of the data. Here is the code I used.

I am trying to use a rotary encoder with the HCTL-2021-A00 from avago. I am getting data output from the IC, but only one of the two bytes which it should be providing. When I move the encoder forward, it will only give me the LOW byte and all of the high bits will be zero. However, when I move the encoder backward, all of the high data bits are 1, and the low data bits still operate normally, counting the position. What could cause the high data bits to all be 1 when moving backward, and all 0 when moving forward? Code used is below.

```
#include <SD.h>
#include<SPI.h>

File datafile;
const int chipSelect = 10; // connected to the CS pin on the sd card, Make sure the card is formatted
int encoderpos=0;
int i=0;
int pulses, A_SIG=0, B_SIG=1;
int b[15];  //the individual bits of data read from the IC
int pos; //position output of IC ranging from 0 to 5000 for 1 revolution
int selpin=1, OEpin=2;
int clock=4;
int d[7]; //the pins on the IC attached to which digital teensy pins
double deg; //degree position of the servo as found from the encoder and IC



void setup()
{
  //set pwm signal for timer input
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  analogWriteFrequency(4, 6000000); // Teensy 3.0 pin 3 also changes to 375 kHz
analogWrite(4, 128);
   //First setup and attach the pins used to communicate with the IC and encoder
  d[0]=22;//pin numbers for attaching the IC to the teensy
  d[1]=21;
  d[2]=20;
  d[3]=19;
  d[4]=18;
  d[5]=17;
  d[6]=16;
  d[7]=15;
//first set pins as inputs and outputs
pinMode(selpin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(OEpin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(d[0], INPUT);
pinMode(d[1], INPUT);
pinMode(d[2], INPUT);
pinMode(d[3], INPUT);
pinMode(d[4], INPUT);
pinMode(d[5], INPUT);
pinMode(d[6], INPUT);
pinMode(d[7], INPUT);

digitalWrite(selpin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(OEpin, HIGH);

pinMode(5, OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
delay(5);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);
delay(5);
digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
delay(5);

pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
SD.begin();
datafile=SD.open("c.txt", FILE_WRITE);
pinMode(7, INPUT);
pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

}



void loop()
{
datafile.println(pose());
if (millis()>4000)
{
  datafile.close();
}

delay(5);
}


int pose()     //Gives the position in degrees from the readings from encoder and IC for 0 to 5000 representing one revolution
{
    digitalWrite(selpin, LOW);     // The sel pin on the IC
  digitalWrite(OEpin, LOW);     // The OE pin on the IC
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(4, LOW);
analogWrite(4, 128);

  b[0]=digitalRead(d[0]);
  b[1]=digitalRead(d[1]);
  b[2]=digitalRead(d[2]);
  b[4]=digitalRead(d[4]);
  b[5]=digitalRead(d[5]);
  b[6]=digitalRead(d[6]);
  b[7]=digitalRead(d[7]);
if(digitalRead(7)==1)
{
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
}
else if(digitalRead(7)==0)
{
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
}
  digitalWrite(selpin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(4, LOW);
analogWrite(4, 128);

  b[8]=digitalRead(d[0]);
  b[9]=digitalRead(d[1]);
  b[10]=digitalRead(d[2]);
  b[11]=digitalRead(d[3]);
  b[12]=digitalRead(d[4]);
  b[13]=digitalRead(d[5]);
  b[14]=digitalRead(d[6]);
  b[15]=digitalRead(d[7]);

  digitalWrite(OEpin, HIGH);


  pos=0;
  i=8;
  for(i; i>0; i--)
  {
pos=2*pos+b[i-1];
  }

  i=16;
  for (i; i>8; i--)
  {
    pos=2*pos+b[i-1];
  }


  return pos;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. 
I had assumed that the rst pin was supposed to be held low unless you wanted to reset the count on the encoder, and was ignoring it the whole time. Once I held the reset pin high, the count started to show up.

As of now there are still problems, I cannot read the high byte from the IC.

Comment: Probably because you are still mishandling the clock

Comment: I also changed the clock to force up and down after changing sel and oe. These changes are now reflected in the code above. Would this still be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to just put this in a comment but apparently still don't have the rep to do that, so taking a stab at answering.

Sounds to me like you are having physical layer corruption issues.  I highly doubt that your wires were too fine a gauge since these are just signal wires for SPI, however, it was instructive that you did that since larger wires seemed to make the problem worse, I would guess that you have too large capacitance on the wire for the datarate you have chosen.

When I am debugging any serial communications for the first time, the first thing I do until communication is reliable is to slow the data rate down.  Something like 10kHz should work in most cases.  See if this fixes the corrupted data.  If it does, go back to a finer gauge wire and then bump the speed back up til you see corruption issues.  If you have a logic analyzer or a scope you can get on the line, it will be very educational to see what is going on with your edge rates.

Comment: Would that just involve adding a delay in between the times I call the pose() function?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overlooking (or at least mishandling) the fact that these parts are built with a bus interface where the /OE and SEL signals as well as the internal position data latch are *sampled* synchronously with a clock input which you do not seem to be driving.

- You need to generate a low-to-high transition of the CLK signal to latch the count into the readout
- You need to generate a high-to-low transition of the CLK signal to latch in chosen values of the /OE and SEL signals.

On second examination of your code, perhaps you are trying to use a free-running clock asynchronous to your reading.  That, however, is extremely unwise.  First, you don't know that a suitable clock edge will happen between when you set the /OE or SEL and when you try to read the data.  Next, you do not know that an *undesired* clock edge will *not* happen in the midst of reading data, causing you to end up with a corrupted value that contains some "old" bits from before the clock edge and some "new" bits from after.  This would be particularly bad if it happened across a transition such as 0b01111111 to 0b10000000 or similar...

You may have other problems as well - your question is not complete without a schematic diagram of how you have wired up this chip.

Comment: The IC has an internal inhibit to stop new data from being transfered to the pins after both OE and SEL are low, until both OE and SEL are high again. Unless I am mistaken, this means I won't have to worry about clock signals in the middle of data reading.

Comment: No, it doesn't - it would only mean that if you could verify that the critical clock transition occurred *between* when you set these signals and started reading, and not at some point in the midst of reading... which at present you can't.  **Your asynchronous approach is fundamentally broken.**  If you want to keep the free-running clock, at minimum you will have to have your program wait for suitable clock transitions between settings and readout.

Comment: Is there a way to get the OE and SEL signals to be syncronous with the clock? or any way to insure there is a clock transition after changing them without using a delay?

Comment: Either drive the clock explicitly in code after you set the control signals, or else read back the clock and wait for the necessary transition between setting the control signals and reading the data.